# Get specific node in xml?

Tags: php, simplexml

my xml is structured as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<users>
    <user>
        <name>
            foo
        </name>
        <token>
            jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk
        </token>
        <connection>
            <host>
                localhost
            </host>
            <username>
                root
            </username>
            <dbName>
                Test
            </dbName>
            <dbPass>
                123456789
            </dbPass>
        </connection>
    </user>
    <user>
        ... same structure...
    </user>
</users>
```

I made this code that iterate through all xml node:

```
function getConString($node)
{
   $item = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "con");
   $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($item);
   $result = $nodes[0];

   foreach($result as $item => $value)
   {
      if($item == "token")
      {
         return $value->__toString();
     }
   }
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is that when $node is equal to:

```
jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk
```

the connection node is returned as array, how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

For someone that doesn't have understood, simply I want that if I insert the token: `jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk` the connection of the user with the token `jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk` will be returned. So in this case I want get all the content of `connection` node and create a connection string:

```
<connection>
            <host>
                localhost
            </host>
            <username>
                root
            </username>
            <dbName>
                Test
            </dbName>
            <dbPass>
                123456789
            </dbPass>
        </connection>
```

Comment: So you want a function where you can search the xml by token, and then return the connection as as an array? This looks very inefficient. Might as well create a single xml per user, with token as the filename. Then just open that file and extract the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, some considerations about your XML code. I don't know if your real XML is formatted exactly as above, but if is it, it's important to highlight that XML whitespaces behavior is different from HTML: usually without DTD or XML schema definition, all whitespaces are significant whitespaces and should be preserved. Also with DTD or XML schema definitions, **the whitespaces in the content are significant**.

This means that with this XML:

```
<token>
    jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk
</token>
```

the `<token>` assume the value `'\n    jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk\n'` (\n = line break) instead of `'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk'`.

This makes it difficult find the token using xPath without pre-modify the xml (you can use regex for it). You can use the `contains()` xPath syntax for this, but (theoretically) it can return more than one result.

I don't know if you have tested your code above, but also in that `$value->__toString()` return something like `'\n    jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk\n'` (it can change depending of indentation level). To return only the token value, you have to change your code in:

```
return trim( $value->__toString() );
```

My advice is to change anyway your XML in this way:

```
<user>
    <name>foo</name>
    <token>jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk</token>
    <connection>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <username>root</username>
        <dbName>Test</dbName>
        <dbPass>123456789</dbPass>
    </connection>
</user>
```

because this is the most correct way to store data: if the XML is produced by you, change it should not be too difficult.

Anyway, I propose you two different functions - one with xPath, one without.

#### Function 1 (xPath) works only with modified XML:

```
function getConString( $token )
{
    $data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "con");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $data );

    $path = '//users/user/token[text()="'.$token.'"]';
    $found = $xml->xpath( $path );
    if( ! count( $found ) ) return False;

    $node = $found[0]->xpath('parent::*')[0];
    return (array) $node->connection;
}
```

#### Function 2, works with old and new XML:

```
function getConString( $token )
{
    $data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "con");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $data );

    foreach( $xml->user as $user )
    {
        if( trim($user->token->__toString()) == $token )
        {
            $retval = array();
            foreach( $user->connection[0] as $key => $val )
            { $retval[$key] = trim($val); }
            return $retval;
        }
    }

    return False;
}
```

#### Edit:

In the comments, you ask: “is possible take the connection node such as host, dbName ect... separate and save it in a specific variable”?

I do not understand what problems they can create this syntax:

```
$user = getConString( 'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk' );
mysqli_connect ( $user['host'], $user['username'], $user['dbPass'], $user['dbName'] );
```

BTW, you can put returned value in separate variables in this way:

```
$user = getConString( 'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk' );
foreach( $user as $key => $val ) $$key = $val;
mysqli_connect ( $host, $username, $dbPass, $dbName );
```

or - if you want specific variable names - change the 2nd function above in this way:

```
(...)
$retval = array();
foreach( $user->connection[0] as $key => $val )
{ $retval[] = trim($val); }
(...)
```

and then call it in this way:

```
list( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbDb, $dbPass ) = getConString( 'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk' );
mysqli_connect ( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbDb );
```

You can change the variable names inside `list` with your preferred names. The function modification is necessary because `list`
doesn't work with associative arrays.

---

- See more about [Whitespace in XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html)
- See more about [list() constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: Very good explaination @fusion3k, i just want ask a question: is possible take the connection node such as host, dbName ect... separate and save it in a specific varialble?

Comment: I don't understand. You want 4 variables like $host, $username etc..? and if is it, when you want it? in the global scope?

Comment: exactly for make a connection string and return the connection string to put in mysqli

Comment: you can comfortably use array for this: `mysqli_connect ($array['host'], $array['username'], $array['dbPass'], $array['dbName'])` Otherwise, you can modify the 2nd function in this way `$retval[] = trim($val);` and then call it through `list( $host,$user,$db,$pass ) = getConString2( 'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk' );`: then use the variables `$host`, `$user`, `$db`, `$pass`

Comment: uhm I don't understand correctly, could you post a bit example please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not averse to using `DOMDocument` rather than `simpleXML` then you should be able to make use of the following. If not and you must use `simpleXML` the XPath query could be ported over for use with `simplexml->xpath`

```
$strxml='<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<users>
    <user>
        <name>
            foo
        </name>
        <token>
            jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk
        </token>
        <connection>
            <host>
                localhost
            </host>
            <username>
                root
            </username>
            <dbName>
                Test
            </dbName>
            <dbPass>
                123456789
            </dbPass>
        </connection>
    </user>
    <user>
        ... same structure...
    </user>
</users>';


/* an array to store details of connection */
$conndetails=array();
/* The particular value to be searched for in token nodes */
$var='jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk';


/* create the DOM objects & load xml source */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* Run the query to find the token with particular value - then it's next sibling */
$results=$xp->query('//token[contains( text(), "'.$var.'" )]/following-sibling::connection');

if( $results ){/* iterate through childnodes and store details in array */
    foreach( $results as $node ) {
        foreach( $node->childNodes as $child ) if( $child->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) $conndetails[ $child->tagName ]=$child->nodeValue;
    }
}

print_r( $conndetails );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make one of these options into a function, but you should be able to understand how to do it, seeing this code. This will show you how to retrieve the information you want.

Option 1:

```
# using iteration
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($data->item as $item){
    if ($item->user->token == 'jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk')
    {
        echo "host: " . $item->user->connection->host . "<br />";
        echo "username: " . $item->user->connection->username . "<br />";
        echo "dbName: " . $item->user->connection->dbName . "<br />";
        echo "dbPass: " . $item->user->connection->dbPass . "<br />";
    } else { continue; }
}
```

Option 2:

```
# using xpath
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// Here we find the element token = jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk and get it's parent
$nodes = $data->xpath('//users/user/token[.="jfhsjfhksdjfhsjkfhksjfsdk"]/parent::*');
$user = $nodes[0];
echo "host: " . $user->connection->host . "<br />";
echo "username: " . $user->connection->username . "<br />";
echo "dbName: " . $user->connection->dbName . "<br />";
echo "dbPass: " . $user->connection->dbPass . "<br />";
```

Comment: I get `trying to get property of non-object` in the condition. this is the value of `$nodes` in my function: http://pastebin.com/USueWHEA