# Trouble parsing the HTTPS response for token in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing, https

I've been struggling to parse an https response for the token value that I need for future https calls.

To parse the token out of a JSON response, I've tried the following:

```
$doc = json_decode($response, true);
token = $doc["result"]["token"];
```

To parse the token out of an XML response, I've tried the following:

```
$json = json_encode($response);
$token = json_decode($json,TRUE)['raw_body'];
```

In python to parse the JSON for the token all I had to do was the following:

```
token = json.loads(data.text)["result"]["token"]
```

If I copy paste the console output of the token into the later https calls
it works perfectly fine, so I thought that maybe I could "cheat" a little and capture the console output and use that instead, so I tried the following:

```
ob_start();
echo $token;
$test = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $test;
```

However, that didn't work either. The next thing I thought is that the result of my 'parsing' had some sort of weird characters that are causing the token to fail in future https calls. So I tried the following:

```
$token = preg_replace("/[^\w]+/", " ", $data['raw_body']);
```

And that gave me an interesting response:
"xml version 1 0 encoding UTF 8 result xmlns [url was here] portal token 7eae331326c9363c9cf47ef58c1d844422dabb0 token result"

So I thought I could split the string by its spaces and pull out the token. However, that didn't work either.

In Python my full code looked like this:

```
# Request Token
data = requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data={'apikey': APIKEY, "format": "json"},
                     auth=HTTPDigestAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
# Parse JSON for Token
token = json.loads(data.text)["result"]["token"]
```

In PHP, this is what I have:

```
$data = array(
        'apikey' => $this->api_key,
        'format' => 'xml');
    Unirest\Request::auth($this->username, $this->password, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    $response = Unirest\Request::post(self::build_url("auth", "get-token")
 // lots of comments of attempts below
```

Any ideas? This is my first week with PHP and I'm totally lost.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific node in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242420/get-specific-node-in-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

I definitely made it more complicated than it had to be.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->body);
 $token = $xml->token;
```